# print amount of records based on two dates

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to get amount of record based on two dates in MySql, example table :

| id | data | datetime_1 | datetime_2. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | row data 1 | 2021-06-28 10:00:00 | 2021-07-02 10:00:00 |

and I want the result like this :

| id | data | datetime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | row data 1 | 2021-06-28 10:00:00 |
| 2 | row data 1 | 2021-06-29 10:00:00 |
| 3 | row data 1 | 2021-06-30 10:00:00 |
| 4 | row data 1 | 2021-07-01 10:00:00 |
| 5 | row data 1 | 2021-07-02 10:00:00 |

is that possible ?

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: I removed inconsistent tags , please tag only the database you are using.

Comment: you could do this by `PROCEDURE `

Comment: You can keep your dates in typeof timestamp (or in milliseconds), then also you need to take two dates in milliseconds too. So, you can filter the records in that interval.

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: Its very hard to achieve it through MySQL. __Why dont you do it using your programming language like php or python ?__  it will be easier to achieve it. Just get records and for each record , run a loop between date1 to date2 and build your data.

Answer (score 1):

You would typically handle this requirement via a calendar table, which is a table containing a sequence of dates which you expect to need in your query.  Here is an example, where I have used an inline union subquery in place of a formal calendar table:

```sql
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT '2021-06-28 10:00:00' AS dt UNION ALL
    SELECT '2021-06-29 10:00:00' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2021-06-30 10:00:00' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2021-07-01 10:00:00' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2021-07-02 10:00:00'
)

SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t2.dt) AS id,
    t1.data,
    t2.dt AS datetime
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN dates t2
    ON t2.dt BETWEEN t1.datetime_1 AND t1.datetime_2
ORDER BY
    t2.dt;
```

Comment: `datetime_1` and `datetime_2` can be any date. How this will work for different dates ?

Comment: @IndraKumarS Maybe my answer is misleading, or maybe you've never worked with calendar tables.  The calendar table can easily be made large enough to cover any required dates.

Comment: Yes i never worked with calendar table! Will check and understand what it is . Thank you

Comment: Tried it. Works like a charm! +1

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH RECURSIVE date_ranges AS (
SELECT datetime_1 AS dt1, datetime_2 dt2 FROM mytable 
UNION ALL
SELECT dt1+INTERVAL 1 DAY, dt2 FROM date_ranges WHERE dt1 < dt2)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dt1) AS id,
       b.data, dt1 as datetime FROM date_ranges a JOIN 
mytable b ON a.dt1 BETWEEN datetime_1 AND b.datetime_2;
```

You can use this method to generate a date range based on your existing data. The final query might need other functions like `MAX()` etc. depending on your data but with the current sample that you've provided, this should suffice.

[Fiddle with additional scenario](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=03b65c909409e62cb496485a72f6611d)